# Why is blender failing to start up?

Tags: error

so i recently had a virus that deleted the files for my computer to start up and i reinstalled windows 10 on my computer and when i reinstalled blender it failed to start quoting this message.
so i deleted it and got the 32bit version and same error, deleted and installed 64bit, same error.

[image]

Comment: i am not good with computers so i really need the help and am thankful for it

Comment: Did you reinstall Windows 10 as 32bit? That would have caused the issue, as Blender needs a 64bit OS and hardware to run.

Comment: no i reinstalled 64bit